# How to detect AutomationElement name change

Tags: c#, event-handling, microsoft-ui-automation

I am using UI Automation in a C# program.  I have managed to acquire an element using its Automation ID.  However, it exposes no patterns.  Using UI Spy, I can see the text I want under Identification->Name.  However, when I try to register an event to detect a change of text, nothing happens; the event handler does not get called.

UI Spy doesn't show any ControlPatterns.  Does this mean I must manually poll for changes to the element's "name" or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to implement this kind of event yourself, by manually polling the `Name` property, or rather continuously calling `FindFirst` with the old name, until it returns no result.

Comment: Why is this the case?  Does the "property changed" event not get triggered for the name?